# NVidia driver Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I'm currently trying to set nvidia driver on Ubuntu 22.04 5.19.0-41-generic RTX 3080

And I'm struggling with NVidia drivers installation(probably as every linux user))

First, I've removed all previous nvidia packages and have installed `nvidia-driver-470`

```
$ dkms status
nvidia/470.182.03, 5.19.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-71-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.19.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.19.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB] (rev a1)
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver
ii  nvidia-driver-470                                           470.182.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
```

I've also tried `nvidia-driver-525, nvidia-driver-530, nvidia-driver-530-open`, behavior was the same.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: *"Does anyone know what is the problem"* - I'm not certain that anyone will, because you didn't tell us what is the problem...

Comment: I have yet to try 22.04, so based on experience with earlier Ubuntu versions: Make sure to remove ALL nvidia related software when attempting to swap driver. `dpkg --list | grep -E ^ii.*nvidia` (`ii` for' installed' and without `-driver`) might be a start

Comment: @Nmath - what you're commenting may well be a translation-caused issue, i.e. not being fluent in English

Comment: @Hannu Perhaps, but there are not many details about the problem. Nvidia drivers are generally configured when the system is installed. It's not clear when or how they became misconfigured, or if they were ever set up correctly to begin with. It's also not very clear what methods are being attempted to install drivers and so there are also no details about the results of those attempts, like error messages or logs that could help identify the problem well enough to know the solution.

Comment: Yes, and: your comment now is more constructive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i my case, the booted kernel was not the kernel, dkms build the modules, so after looking at 'uname -r' showed an oem kernel. In this case i needed to boot into the right kernel (hint grub_default) and then deinstalled the oem kernel. After this, nvidia-smi worked.